# Attachment in Jenkins with dynamic folder?

Tags: java, jenkins

When running Selenium.. The results are created in the following structure..

```
reports -> Date (10032018) -> Run1 -> result.html
reports -> Date (10032018) -> Run2 -> result.html
reports -> Date (10042018) -> Run1 -> result.html
etc....
```

I just wanted to pick it up attachment which is latest created? Because when script run date and run is dynamic.. How to give this folder name to Jenkins to pick up result.html to send in mail?

Attachments -> reports/{date}/{run}/result.html

I can write this attachment path in the external file.. Can we read this file using Jenkins and give this parameter in the attachment field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , i need solution for this ,even i m not able to get the report files in email notifications ,

Here is my project structure like this

[image]